# make a neural network continue number patterns

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I discovered neural netwaorks a few time ago and i now how they work
but i have a question: how can I train a NN countinue number patterns, 
e.g. 0,2,4,6,8 as a input and 10,12,14,16,18 as output.
I dont know how to make this, but I thought about a input [0,1,2,3,4] and 
output [0,2,4,6,8],what means 0 is the first number of the stream and 3 the third
Can this work or what are the other ways.

Comment: I understand your post that you would apply n(input)=n+10(output) using a neural network? If you confirm this I will provide the detailed answer how to do it.

Comment: A neural-network is the wrong approach for this problem. There are a lot of caveats and it's not a problem NNs were designed for. You are thinking about input-output architecture, but the real problems will come sooner or later. (Assumption: you want to train your NN to handle multiple different patters; not only a stride of 2)